# Monitor individual Queue in Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have a Rails Project that has Multiple Queues. I have the capability to login and monitor the redis. but it is showing info from all queues. Is there a way to only show the information for a single queue?

```
telnet localhost 6379
AUTH {PASSWORD}
MONITOR
```

these are my QUEUES

```
  - user_posting
  - notify_queue
  - load_posting
  - truck_posting
  - hotload_posters_posting
  - major_posters_posting
  - scrape_posting
  - second_chance
```

would like to see just truck_posting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick solution is to grep what you want, for example:

```
redis-cli MONITOR | grep truck_posting
```

Another idea is to use [keyspace notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications).